# 1 post, 2 templates

Tags: posts, templates, single

I want to be able to render post in two different styles (2 templates).

For example, let's say I have the post ID 133, I would like two URLS to access it and so it renders where different template would apply.

- lorem.com/render1/133
- lorem.com/render2/1333

for example... or it could be something like:

- lorem.com/post/133
- and lorem.com/post/133?template=2

How would you do it?

Comment: Just a heads up, a query var (your ?template=2) example might be safe, but be careful about duplicate content. If WordPress correctly adds the canonical address meta tag, I think you'll be safe, but it's better to avoid the issue than suddenly find your site tanked on Google overnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be the [Rewrite Endpoints API](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/). The API allows you to create post URLs with endpoints like `lorem.com/post/133/json/` or `lorem.com/post/133/print/`. You'll find useful code examples in the link provided.

Comment: Clean. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a query arg, via [**`add_query_arg()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg), you could then *query* that query arg, via [**`get_query_var()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var), inside of a callback hooked into [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

(Note: how/why you add the query arg is outside the scope of this answer.)

For example:

```
function wpse82168_template_redirect() {
    // You'll need to update these conditionals according to your context
    if ( is_single() && get_query_var( 'template' ) && '2' == get_query_var( 'template' ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'template-2' );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse82168_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Interesting technic :) Is there a particular explanation for you function name (wpse82168_template_redirect) or it's just random?

Comment: All declared function names are, ultimately, arbitrary. But in this case, `wpse82168` refers to *this question*, and `template_redirect` refers to *what the function does*. The former is a unique prefix that ensures the function is properly namespaced; the latter is *inherent documentation*, in which simply reading the function name helps explain the purpose of the function.